# Passing props via redux (or a simpler way if possible) through Route or Link

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have been flipping through search results and googling like an addict chasing that amber baby rattle. I am finding nothing which uses React-Router -v 4. I am building a simple(lol simple in theory) application which uses axios to pass user profiles to a Home component which then maps the response and displays a gird of avatars and names. This works fine. The problem is, I want to click on one of those avatars then pass that specific data which is associated with that avatar to a new individual user page by using the id params. So click on avatar open user profile. I know before react-router -v 4 it seems you could actually just pass a method directly into a route but this is not working for me. Any help would greatly help me with this puzzle.

Action

```
import axios from 'axios'
const URI = '###'

export function fetchUsers () {
 return function (dispatch) {
  axios.get (URI)
  .then ((response) => {
    dispatch({
     type: 'FETCH_USERS_FULFILLED',
     payload: response.data.users
   })
 })
   .catch ((err) => {
     dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_USERS_REJECTED',
      payload: err
     })
    })
   }
  }
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  users: [],
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null
}

export default function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case 'FETCH_USERS_LOADING': {
     return {
      ...state,
      fetching: true,
      fetched: false,
      users: action.payload
     }
   }
   case 'FETCH_USERS_FULFILLED': {
     return {
      ...state,
      fetching: false,
      fetched: true,
      users: action.payload
    }
  }
  case 'FETCH_USERS_REJECTED': {
    return {
     ...state,
     fetching: false,
     error: action.payload
   }
  }
}
```

return state
   }

Store

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducers from '../reducers'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger())

const store = createStore(
 reducers,
 compose(middleware, window.devToolsExtension ? 
 window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
)

export default store
```

Home

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Profile from '../Profile'
import { fetchUsers } from '../redux/actions/userActions'

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
     }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchUsers();
 }

 render () {
   return (
     <div className={'view-wrapper'}>
       <div className={'home-container'}>
         {this.props.users.map((user, i) =>
           <Profile {...this.props} key={i} i={i} user={user}/>
         )}
       </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
    users:   state.user.users,
    fetched: state.user.fetched,
    error:   state.user.error
   }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
    fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers())
   }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Profile

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Profile = (props) => (
  <div className='profile-container'>
    <Link to={`/profile/${props.id}`}>
     <img
       src={props.avatar}
       className={'user-avatar'}
       alt={props.name}
      />
     </Link>
   </div>
  )

  export default Profile
```

Routes

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route path='/profile/:id' component={Profile}/>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're half way there.  You don't need to pass the data (props) along to the individual user page, instead, use the id in the route so the individual user page knows what record in the Store it wants.  In your individual user component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    user: state.user.users.find( (user) => (user.id === props.match.params.id) )
  };
};
```

Then you can access 'user' as a prop in the component.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (bundle.js:35738)
    at mapToPropsProxy (bundle.js:3912)
    at Function.detectFactoryAndVerify (bundle.js:3921)
    at mapToPropsProxy (bundle.js:3912)
    at handleFirstCall (bundle.js:35130)
    at pureFinalPropsSelector (bundle.js:35178)
    at Object.runComponentSelector [as run] (bundle.js:3230)
    at Connect.initSelector (bundle.js:3382)
    at new Connect (bundle.js:3323)
    at constructClassInstance (bundle.js:21071)

Comment: Sorry - I should have paid more attention to your existing state - I've edited the answer

Comment: I can see how this will work but I am getting a map error                 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Home.render (bundle.js:35723)
                                                         
 Thank you for your help

Comment: Hmm thats a problem with this line: "{this.props.users.map((user, i) =>".  Wasn't the Home component working before?  Remember that the above mapStateToProps function is for the Profile component

Comment: Yeah worked before as far as mapping the data and passing to the child Profile. Hmm

Comment: Ah!  the problem is that you are setting the user prop in the Profile component (with the code provided above) but also trying to pass it down to the component inside the Home component.  I'd be inclined to let the Profile component stay dumb, create a ProfilePage component to be a container with the mapStateToProps function above, and have the ProfilePage component pass the user prop down to the Profile component

Comment: Thank you for your help, I marked as correct because the error is my knowledge of redux. I ended up putting this together to make it work    
 return { user: state.user.users[ownProps.match.params.id - 1]};